# How to make concurrent API calls in C#?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am needing to pull custom fields from a mortgage API.
The problem is that there are 11000 records in total and it takes 1 second per API request. I want to find a way to send requests asynchronously and in parallel  to make this more efficient.

I have tried looping through all the requests then having a `Task.WaitAll()` to wait for a response to return. I only receive two responses then the application waits indefinitely.

I first set up a static class for the `HttpClient`

```cs
 public static class ApiHelper
    {
        public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

        public static void InitializeClient()
        {
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        }
    }
```

I gather my mortgage ID list and loop through the API Post Calls

```cs
        static public DataTable GetCustomFields(DataTable dt, List<string> cf, string auth)
        {

                //set auth header
                ApiHelper.ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth);

                //format body
                string jsonBody = JArray.FromObject(cf).ToString();
                var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

               

                var responses = new List<Task<string>>();


                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    
                    string guid = dr["GUID"].ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""); //remove {} from string
                    
                    responses.Add(GetData(guid, content));

                }

                Task.WaitAll(responses.ToArray());
                //some code here to process through the responses and return a datatable

                return updatedDT;

        }
```

Each API call requires the mortgage ID (GUID) in the URL

```cs
  async static Task<string> GetData(string guid, StringContent json)
        {

            string url = "https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/loans/" + guid + "/fieldReader";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has started .....", guid);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.PostAsync(url, json))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} has returned response....", guid);
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                
            }

        }
```

I'm only testing 10 records right now and send all 10 requests.
But I only receive two back.

Result is:

[image: here].

Could you please advise me on the right way of sending the concurrent API calls?

Comment: Take a look at TPL DataFlow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `GetData` `Task` are using the same `HttpClient` singleton instance. The HttpClient cannot server multiple calls at the same time. Best practice is to use a `Pool` of HttpClient to ensure there is no Task accessing the same HttpClient at the same time.

Also, be careful throwing `exception` in Task, it will stops the `WaitAll()` at first thrown exception

**Solution** I've posted the entire project here : https://github.com/jonathanlarouche/stackoverflow_58137212

This solution send 25 requests using a `max sized` pool of [3];

Basically, the `ApiHelper` contains an `HttpClient` ***pool***, using the Generic class **`ArrayPool<T>`**. ***You can use any other Pooling library, I just wanted to post a self-contained solution***.

**Suggested ApiHelper** Bellow, this class now contains a pool and a `Use` method that receive an `Action`, an Item from the pool will be "rented" for the duration of the Action, then it will be returned into the pool via the `ArrayPool.Use` function. `Use` function receive also the apiToken to change the Request Auth Header.

```
public static class ApiHelper
{
    public static int PoolSize { get => apiClientPool.Size; }

    private static ArrayPool<HttpClient> apiClientPool = new ArrayPool<HttpClient>(() => {
        var apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        return apiClient;
    });

    public static Task Use(string apiToken, Func<HttpClient, Task> action)
    {
        return apiClientPool.Use(client => {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiToken);
            return action(client);
        });
    }
}
```

**GetData** function. Get Data will receive the apiToken and will await the `ApiHelper.Use` function. New instance of `StringContent()` object need to be done in this function as it cannot be reused across different Http Post Call.

```
async static Task<string> GetData(string apiToken, Guid guid, string jsonBody)
{

    string url = "https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/loans/" + guid + "/fieldReader";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has started .....", guid);
    string output = null;
    await ApiHelper.Use(apiToken, (client) => 
    {
        var json = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return client.PostAsync(url, json).ContinueWith(postTaskResult =>
        {

            return postTaskResult.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(s => {

                output = s.Result;
                return s;
            });
        });
    });
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has finished .....", guid);
    return output;
}
```

**ArrayPool**

```
public class ArrayPool<T>
{
    public int Size { get => pool.Count(); }
    public int maxSize = 3;
    public int circulingObjectCount = 0;
    private Queue<T> pool = new Queue<T>();
    private Func<T> constructorFunc;

    public ArrayPool(Func<T> constructorFunc) {
        this.constructorFunc = constructorFunc;
    }

    public Task Use(Func<T, Task> action)
    {
        T item = GetNextItem(); //DeQueue the item
        var t = action(item);
        t.ContinueWith(task => pool.Enqueue(item)); //Requeue the item
        return t;
    }

    private T GetNextItem()
    {
        //Create new object if pool is empty and not reached maxSize
        if (pool.Count == 0 && circulingObjectCount < maxSize)
        {
            T item = constructorFunc();
            circulingObjectCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Pool empty, adding new item");
            return item;
        }
        //Wait for Queue to have at least 1 item
        WaitForReturns();

        return pool.Dequeue();
    }

    private void WaitForReturns()
    {
        long timeouts = 60000;
        while (pool.Count == 0 && timeouts > 0) { timeouts--; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); }
        if(timeouts == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Wait timed-out");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not instantiate a new `HttpClient` for each request. It will kill your application.

Comment: If you are using .Net Core, he can use HttpClientFactory instead that handles pooling

Comment: @billybob I totally agree, that's why i've pointed the Pool option in my answer, I wanted to point out the fact that using the same instance at the same time just not work. Running 10 parallel request will require 10 instances

Comment: I just wanted to point out to the OP that it might not be a good idea to create a new instance each time, since he has 1100 calls to the API.

Comment: I will change my answer to use a simple implementation of an HttpClient pool in case he uses asp.net

Comment: @billybob Changed the solution to uses a Pool with simple implementation in case he's not using .Net core. Thanks for your comments :D

Comment: It is nice that you have time to fix your answer!

Comment: If I have time, I will try to post an answer using TPL Dataflow to perform multiple calls at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both.
I'm going to do some further testing to verify this works.

Comment: This fixed the problem.  I can't thank you enough for your work on this.  You went above and beyond. 

I do need to do some education on ArrayPools as I have never used those before, but processed through 1000 request in 99 seconds vs what was 16 mins